# How can I use @HostListener('window:beforeunload') to call a method?

Tags: angular, debugging, onbeforeunload, angular-components

I am trying to call a post method I made myself before my component is unloaded, but it doesn't work.

I put a breakpoint on @HostListener and it doesn't break there when I open a different component.

I'm using Chrome to debug and I turned on Event Listener Breakpoints for unload and beforeunload, which do break when I open a different component.

[image]

Am I missing something in my code?

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

Component({
    templateUrl: 'new-component.html'    
})

export class NewComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload') onBeforeUnload() {
            PostCall();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`window:beforeunload` is a browser event which is triggered right before actually unloading the page.

When you navigate to another component, you are not actually unloading the page.

What you need to do is use `ngOnDestroy` which will be called when component is being destroyed. Implements the following interface:

https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

Example:

```
export class NewComponent implements OnDestroy{
    ngOnDestroy() {
            PostCall();
    }
}
```

Comment: ngOnDestory is not called on page refresh case.

Comment: Which is not the initial problem of the author. "I am trying to call a post method I made myself before my component is unloaded, but it doesn't work."

Comment: yes, i just put a comment as i was searching something related and got this result, so just put a comment so to help others like me :)

Comment: Do any angular lifecycle hooks preempt page refresh?

Comment: I use both events - ngOnDestroy and window:beforeunload - to save the grid column settings or whatever needs to be done when the user exits the page.

Answer (score 30):

Try like this :

```
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event) {
    this.PostCall();
}

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    return false;
}

PostCall() {
    console.log('PostCall');
}
```

Comment: The first HostListener does not really work anymore for me: on renavigation from the page, the `PostCall` method is not called.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the `window:beforeunload` event with HostListener, the listener will be destroyed with the component.

Return false will make an alert :)

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  onBeforeUnload() {
    return false;
}
```